# Angular lazy loaded module with child component default route

Tags: lazy-loading, angular-router, angular9

Angular 9. Child component is not loaded with lazy loaded module component. Here is my code.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/auth',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
  }
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthRootComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  }
```

When i use **localhost:4200/** it redirects me to **localhose:4200/auth**. It does not load login component.

But when i hit url in browser (**localhost:4200/auth**) it will load login component, and new url will be desired url which is **localhost:4200/auth/login**.

Please tell me, why it does not load login from child array when auth module is loaded and the url is **localhost:4200**?
URL should be **localhost:4200/auth/login** but right now getting url **localhost:4200/auth**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to change from `redirectTo: '/auth'` to `redirectTo: 'auth'`. That is because when you're using **absolute redirects**(e.g `/auth`), only one redirect operation will be allowed, in this case the one which goes to `/auth`, meaning that any other redirects(e.g `redirectTo: 'login'`) will be ignored.

[Here's](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/apply_redirects.ts#L190-L193) where it checks if there were any absolute redirects:

```js
if (allowRedirects && this.allowRedirects) {
    return this.expandSegmentAgainstRouteUsingRedirect(
      ngModule, segmentGroup, routes, route, paths, outlet);
}
```

And [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/apply_redirects.ts#L84-L89) is where it states that after an absolute redirect, there can't be any other redirects:

```js
if (e instanceof AbsoluteRedirect) {
  // after an absolute redirect we do not apply any more redirects!
  this.allowRedirects = false;
  // we need to run matching, so we can fetch all lazy-loaded modules
  return this.match(e.urlTree);
}
```

---

### Absolute vs Relative Redirects

*Excerpt from my [GH repo](https://github.com/Andrei0872/my-dev-notes/blob/master/notebooks/ng/router/redirecting.md#absolute-vs-relative-redirects)*.

The difference between `redirectTo: 'foo/bar'` and `redirectTo: '/foo/bar'` is that:

- / - will start again from the root(the first outermost array of routes)
- `` - will start the search from the first route from the array this current route resides in

Comment: Thanks, i remembered difference between absolute routes and relatives routes, But i did not know, that they go that deep in routing.